# Lambda function is not triggered by dynamodb all the time

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I have a DDB table.

When any record in it is inserted or updated, lambda function should be triggered.

But recently I found when requests are many(many records are inserted or updated a lot), some records would not trigger lambda function (like 10%).

I checked metrics, cloudwatch log in lambda function and low-level API of dynamoDB stream but couldn't find exception or throttled issues.

Also, I did see that modified records are in DDB stream by using low-level api of DDB stream (I can see something like (oldImage:{...}, newImage:{...})). But that just didnt trigger lambda function.

Did anyone have this issue before? or Somewhere else I can check further?
Thx

Comment: By the way, usually all of my records in DDB would be updated continually. If things go well, a record should be updated 15 times and that record would go through lambda function 15 times. But sometimes it would stop at the first step and no more. Couldn't figure out how this happens.

Comment: so you came up with a solution?

Comment: It turns out there is a throttling issue about cloudwatch happening in our lambda and we couldn't notice it because we didn't print it in catch block and "return" is quite meaningless in this case. After fixing that issue, everything is working fine.